# Direct (or inverse) image of subgroup under Second Isomorphism Theorem's isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove this:

> Let $G$ be a group, with $K,V\leq G$, $V\trianglelefteq G$ and $KV=G$. Let
>   $$\varphi:K/K\cap V \to G/V$$
>   given by $k(K\cap V)\mapsto kV$ be the isomorphism of the Second Isomorphism Theorem. Let $H\leq G$ with $V\leq H$.
>
> Then $\varphi((H\cap K)/(K\cap V))=H/V$.

#### My attempt:

I could prove that $\varphi((H\cap K)/(K\cap V))\leq H/V$ like this:

Let $h=k\in H\cap K$. Then $kV=hV$ and $\varphi(k(K\cap V))=kV=hV\in H/V$.

I wanted to prove the converse like this: Let $h\in H$. I want to prove that there exists $k=h'\in H\cap K$ such that $h(K\cap V)=k(K\cap V)$. I don't know how to proceed. My first idea was to take $v_1\in V,k_1\in K$ such that $h=k_1v_1$, but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: Since you have $H\leq K$, $H\cap K=H$. Does that help?

Comment: @ArnaudD.
Sorry, that was a mistake (A big one). It´s not $H\leq K$. It's $H\leq G$. Is the proposition false with $G$?

Comment: I assume $V$ is contained in $H$?

Comment: Yes, it is contained.

Comment: Let $h \in H$. Since $G = KV$ we can write $h = kv$ for some $k \in K$ and $v \in V$. Then we have $hV = kvV = kV$, so $k \in hV$ and $h^{-1}k \in V \leq H$. Consequently $k \in hH = H$. Since also $k \in K$, we have $k \in H \cap K$.

Comment: @Bungo Of course. I was thinking wrong about the converse, I just had to find some $k\in H\cap K$ such that $kV=hV$.

Thanks.

Comment: We have shown that $k \in H \cap K$, so $k(K \cap V)$ is an element of the domain of $\phi$. Then by definition $\phi(k(K \cap V)) = kV$. We already showed that $kV = hV$. Thus to summarize, starting with an arbitrary $h \in H$, we found a $k \in H \cap K$ such that $\phi(k(K \cap V)) = hV$. This proves the containment you need: $H/V \leq \phi((H \cap K)/(K \cap V))$.

Answer (score 1):

*The following summarises @Bungo's answer in the comments.*

---

Let $h\in H$.

By $G=KV,$ there exist $k\in K, v\in V$ such that $h=kv.$ Now $k\in hV$, since $hV=kvV\stackrel{(1)}{=}kV$, so $h^{-1}k\in V\le H.$ Thus $k\in hH=H$. But $k\in K$. Hence $k\in H\cap K$.

Now $k(K\cap V)$ is in the domain of $\varphi$ with $$\varphi (k(K\cap V))=kV\stackrel{(1)}{=}hV$$ by definition.

Hence $$H/V\le\varphi((H\cap K)/(K\cap V))$$ as required.